# Stata egen combined with if

Tags: stata

I have data like this

```
year month X    Y    weight  
2013    1   1    0    1000
2001    12  0     1    2000
```

I want to create a variable `Z` based on the `X` and `Y` variables, conditional on `year`. I have two formulas for `year` before and after 2002. If I use `egen` with `if`,

```
if year > 2002 {
   bysort year month  :egen Z= total( x*weight)
}
else {
bysort year month : egen Z= total(y*weight*0.5)
}
```

this code is not going to work, because if `year <2002` , Stata would report that `z` has already been created. Is there any way to achieve the goal?

I used a very crude and brute force way  to solve this problem. I create two variables for z, namely z and z_2002. Then I replace z with z_2002 if the year is less than 2002.

Comment: The "already created" error is not your only problem. You've incorrectly used the programming **ifcmd**  rather than an **if** qualifier (**help if**). See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/  Only the qualifying **if** can be used to operate on a subset of observations.

Comment: Let's start again. What exactly do you want?

Is it the following:

1. There are two rules one for before 2002, and one for after.
2. Z is the _yearly sum_ of the monthly functions of x or y dependent on the year.


Is this correct?

Comment: z is the monthly sum for each month and year. and the formula for z is different depending on the year.

Comment: @YanSong It seems you have answered your own question by editing the original question. It is great that you have answered your own question. I am not sure if this still counts as a question.

Comment: @fsmart As I said in the question, my method is not elegant enough. I am hoping someone would have a better approach

Comment: The question, as stands especially considering the edits to the question still seems to convey a great degree of confusion as to what is actually being attempted. Are there multiple observations per year month combination? If not, then the `egen` command is not appropriate.

Comment: @fsmart To answer your question, yes, there are multiple observations in each year - month. In fact, there are more than ten thousand in each year -month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clear
input year month x    y    weight
2013    1   1    0    1000
2001    12  0     1    2000
end

preserve
keep if year>2002
bysort year month  :egen z= total(x*weight)
tempfile t1
save `t1'
restore
keep if year<=2002
bysort year month : egen z= total(y*weight*0.5)
append using `t1'
list
```

Comment: Your method would work. What I have done so far is to create two different variables, z and z_2002. Then I replace z with z_2002 if year is before 2002.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this should work.

Compute the products in a first step (conditional on the year) and the sums in a second step.

As other answers already note, there's a difference between the `if` qualifier and the `if` programming command. There's a short FAQ on this: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/.

(I use code provided by @NickCox in a comment to another answer.)

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input year month x    y    weight
2013    1   1    0    1000
2013    1   1    0    800
2013    2   0    1    1200
2013    2   1    0    1400
2001    12  1     0    1500
2001    12  0     1    2000
2001    11  1     1    4000
end

sort year month
list, sepby(year month)

*----- computations -----

gen Z = cond(year > 2002, x * weight, y * weight * 0.5)
bysort year month: egen totZ = total(Z) // already sorted so -by- should be enough

list, sepby(year month)
```

Comment: You could put the `cond()` call inside `total()`, as `total()` feeds on expressions, and doesn't insist that its argument is a variable name.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. True, of course. Although sometimes I'd rather write an additional line or two to increase readability. In this case I was only trying to emphasize the two-step sequence of the solution.

Comment: Nice answer, Roberto.